# Feedreader in KDE

Tags: kde, kubuntu

In the cli I am using Newsboat, and it works great. To manage my feed I rely on the The Old Reader.

I am looking for a nice looking app to do the same in KDE. I am running kubuntu 20.04. I quite like feedreader, but I am not able to amke it work. I have downloaded the flatpack - I have tried to compile it - No luck.

The apps loads find and works up to the point where i try to get the feeds loaded. Nothing happends. The app keep showing offline.

I have the exact same issue as decribed here: https://medium.com/@HashtagSecurity/all-i-wanted-was-a-feed-reader-client-app-51322c1e14c3

Any help welcome :)

Comment: By feed do you mean RSS?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I mean

Comment: Depending on how you view such stuff, but I use the free tier of Feedly - it's web based.

Comment: I tried feedly, for some reason I much prefer the dedicated app apaproche - and I am not a big fan of the feedly interface.

Comment: Thunderbird? Many mail clients have integrated RSS readers.

Comment: I did try this as a fall back plan :) but far from ideal :( -- I got feedreader to work on Manjaro KDE no issues. Just don't know why ubuntu is so fineky ...

Comment: Manjaro is easy if you're willing to install from AUR. Part of why it's my daily driver. Though I'm a Gnome3 user, firmly.

Comment: yeah, it used to be my main. I just recently moved back to kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are actually two versions of feedreader. If you use `sudo apt-get install feedreader`, you will get it to work. The flatpak version has never worked for me, but the apt-get version does. I don't know why.